# XAMPP Preview of PHP Redirects to Main Website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I recently had a third party contractor edit my website so you no longer see the ".php" at the end of each url. I am assuming he changed something with the .htaccess though I haven't been able to get a response from him since this job. Since then if I would like to preview my site for edits with XAMPP running the "localhost/filename" redirects me to my main online url. Is there anything I can change with with my xampp settings or .htaccess to allow me to view a preview for minor edits before uploading? I am not an expert in Apache or .htaccess files.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT Answer:
So this was not an .htaccess issue. It was a little more complicated than I thought. The easiest solution my colleague helped me through is as follows-

First I edited my host files using this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/?fbclid=IwAR3d5pnrWgOdutlcrtThAzpIQSTteESgi6p6eWoPLaE_IPN-C1jZegLJBBI

In my host file I just put

```
127.0.0.1       yourmodel-local.com.
```

Second, I opened up the Apache Config file "httpd.conf" In that file under "ServerName localhost:80" line I added this:

```
    <VirtualHost yourmodel-local.com:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yourmodel/"
ServerName yourmodel-local.com
```

So Now with XAMPP running I can use the yourmodel-local.com as my preview url.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, there's probably a `RewriteRule` or a `Redirect` instruction inside the .htaccess.

Normally those instructions are used to use a specific domain for example always use the https version of [www.site.com](http://www.site.com).

You should look for lines similar to these:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

If you could provide that part of your .htaccess file's code I might be able to indicate what you would need to modify.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the .htaccess file you submitted, the problem is related to lines that get automatically added to your .htaccess from your hosting company's server. The lines that contain strings like `.well-known/acme-challenge` are used for SSL certificate generation.

Your remote .htaccess has these three lines in the beginning:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The # is used for comment meaning those lines aren't being used.

So, I think the easiest solution for you in this case would be to leave the remote .htaccess file as it is, but edit the one you have locally to just contain this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Basically you'll have only this in your local .htaccess and leave the remote as it is, because it also has some PHP configuration lines, which will probably cause a 500 error on your local development environment. Be sure to not include the original # symbols.

Comment: Hi Mihail, Thank you for your comment. I see exactly what you are talking about in the file. You can download that .htaccess file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbki930g5m55l3f/.htaccess?dl=0 There are several instances where I see a "rewriteCond" though I don't see any reference to a direct url as you have written.

Comment: Thank you for looking it over. I did make the changes as you suggested but I am still getting redirected to my online url. I think I isolated the issue down to line 12: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourmodel.space/$1 [R,L] Removing this line alone sends me to my local server but I no longer have any javascript or styling from the rest of my site. Do you think this might be the issue and if so how should I edit it? many thanks!

Comment: Did you leave only what I told you? Literally delete everything else on your local htaccess file. Then just in case delete your browser history or open in incognito mode.

Comment: I tried a few options actually. When I loaded my site with just the first few lines without # of my .htaccess, as you suggested, the site loaded locally but without any styling or javascript even after clearing my browsing history. I then tried to isolate what line was controlling this issue. Are there any other areas I should look at to troubleshoot this issue?